# Does nextAlphaNumericWord exist in 3.0?

Tags: smalltalk

I'm trying to work through these tutorials:  http://live.exept.de/doc/online/english/overview/basicClasses/streams.html

But I can't get some of the methods to work (e.g., nextAlphaNumericWord). Does this or anything like this exist in 2.0/3.0?

---

I've got this bit working decent:

```
[ tmpStream atEnd ] whileFalse: [ myStream nextPutAll: (tmpStream nextDelimited: Character space); nextPut: $ ].
```

This doesn't account for cases such as:  `'one _ _ _ two _ _  three _   four _ _   '` (spaces)

I've also tried:

```
    |tmpStream|
myStream := ReadWriteStream on: String new.
tmpStream := ReadStream on: inString.

[ tmpStream atEnd ] whileFalse: [ tmpStream next == $
                                    ifFalse: [ myStream nextPutAll: 
                                        (tmpStream nextDelimited: $ ); 
                                        nextPut: $
                                    ].
```

But this just chops off the first letter in each word. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have different delimiters, just build a Collection with all your delimiters and test with #includes: when filtering. Also use `Character space` instead of `$ ` because you will run into many problems identifying syntactic and semantic spaces. And check differences between = and == because you don't need identity here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need that old Smalltalk/X version? Current Smalltalk/X version is 6.2.x and contains the #nextAlphaNumericWord method in PeekableStream and ReadStream classes.
However, I highly recommend you to upgrade to the latest Smalltalk/X version so you can enjoy better features.

If you are porting to Pharo 2.0 or 3.0 then you have multiple options to implement that method, but a close approach to the tutorial would be:

```
|string stream word1 word2 num1 num2 num3|

string := 'one two 12345 567.678'.
stream := string readStream.

word1 := stream nextDelimited: Character space.
stream skipSeparators.
word2  := stream upToAnyOf: Character separators.
num1   := Number readFrom: stream.
...
```

Comment: I've added a comment to my original post. Please let me know your thoughts